# FORTRAN - Assigning an array value to variable

Tags: arrays, variables, resize, fortran

Is there a way to get the value of an array to the shape of a variable? Even when I select a single value of an array, say `A(1:1, 1:1)`, it still complains when I compile and want to assign this to a variable:

```
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

The goal in the end is something like this:

```
H = MAXVAL(matrix) - epsilon
IF ( matrix(i:i, i:i) >= H ) THEN
```

...
but I cannot make this comparison because H is a variable and `matrix(i:i, i:i)` a 1x1 array. Is the only possibility for this to work to make H and array, too?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not specify a range, use a single element:

```
A(1,1)=1
```

Your statement would then read:

```
H = MAXVAL(matrix) - epsilon
IF ( matrix(i, i) >= H ) THEN
```

Background:

Fortran allows you to work on sub-arrays like:

```
A(1:10,2:5)
```

which would be a `10x4` array. So `A(1:1,1:1)` is in fact an array (1x1) (as you noted). `A(1,1)`, on the other hand, is a scalar and can be treated as such.

Comment: Thank you! That worked!
Guess the last time I tried it this way around and got an error, I was actually comparing with another array.